# Bot Framework - IDialogStack.PollAsync deprecated after 3.5.0

Tags: botframework

I'm looking at the core-CreateNewConversation sample in the Bot builder examples repo (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples). There is a method available on IDialogStack called PollAsync that seems to be gone after version 3.5.0 of bot builder. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reality, it was just moved from the `IDialogStack` class to the `IDialogTask` class.

Instead of doing:

```
IDialogStack stack = stack = scope.Resolve<IDialogStack>();
```

you have to do

```
IDialogTask task = scope.Resolve<IDialogTask>();
```

then you can just do:

```
task.Call(interruption, null);
await task.PollAsync(token);
```

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/pull/74/files) that is updating the sample taking into account this change.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: @Ezequiel Jadib `task.PollAsync(token);` what does this line do?